Partitions are getting repeated in spring batch
I am using partition in spring batch and pgbouncer (Connection pooler for postgre) and I am creating the Partition in my code using following code -
 public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
    Map<String, ExecutionContext> executionContextMap = new HashMap<>();
    count = this.stepExecution.getJobExecution().getExecutionContext().getLong(DATA_COUNT);

    // no. of records that one grid can accomodate
    int partitionSize = (int) Math.ceil((double) count / gridSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
      long currentMin = i * partitionSize;
      long currentMax = Math.min(currentMin + partitionSize, count);
      ExecutionContext context = new ExecutionContext();
      if (currentMin >= count) {
        // to handle negative limit case
        break;
      }
      context.putLong(OFFSET, currentMin);
      context.putLong(LIMIT, currentMax - currentMin);
      context.put(IS_COMPLETED, false);
      context.put(PARTITION_NO, "partition" + i);
      executionContextMap.put("partition" + i, context);
    }
    return executionContextMap;
  }
}

and in my reader is I am reading the data using jdbcTemplate, after reading the data I am setting the value of property IS_COMPLETED to true so that next time when the same partition will come for execution so it's execution should be skipped because I also have one check if(!IS_COMPLETED) so first time when partition will come to perform read it'll read the data, second time if the same partition will come then i'll return null because that partition is already completed. so this logic is working absolutely fine because from the logs I can see that the value of IS_COMPLETED variable is flipping correctly from false to true.
Now the problem is my code did not throw any error but somehow same partition which is completed is again came back for execution with default value of IS_COMPLETED (false) that I set during partition creation and running the same set of records that are already executed and I am not able to figure out what is the issue here because my code is not throwing any error or exception. Here My partition is running three times where running two times was expected but I am not sure why it's running for the third time with default value of IS_COMPLETED of false. And I also verified that my partition creation logic is also working fine it created the partition only one time for a particular offset, it's not repeating so there is no issue in partition creation logic.
Even I am using SimpleDataSource not Hikari one because I am already using one connection pooler PGBouncer.
